# How to crop the gallery images in appcelerator?

Tags: ios, image, crop, appcelerator

I am developing iOS application. In that I have a requirement to crop the images while uploading the images from gallery.can any one help me how to crop the images in appcelerator for ios platform.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use the internal blob.imageAsCrop() method:

https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Blob-method-imageAsCropped

Properties are width, height, x, y (https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/ImageAsCroppedDict)

It'll returns another blob which you can save or display again

Example:

```
var croppedImage = blob.imageAsCropped({x : 20, y : 20, width : 100, height : 100});
var imageView = Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    image:croppedImage,
    width: 100, height:100
});
```

Example 2:

```
Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        success: function(event) {
            var galleryImage = event.media;

            var dict = {
                x: 0,
                y: 50,
                width: 300,
                height: 300
            };

            var croppedImage = galleryImage.imageAsCropped(dict);

            var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
                image: croppedImage,
                height: 'auto',
                width: 'auto'
            });
            $.index.add(imageView);
        },
        cancel: function() {},
        savedToPhotoGallery: true,
        allowEditing: true,
        mediaTypes: [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
        showControls: true
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for giving reply could you please help me how to use those  two methods with sample example code

Comment: do you have any code you can show? You just need the crop example or the whole "get image from gallery, crop, upload"? A bit more information would be nice

Comment: Hi it's allow the user should only select image .but my requirement is he is going to select fixed length of the image means he only crop the image depends on his requirement

Comment: Hi the following is my code which makes the user selected image as small but my aim is user should select how much crop size he want

Comment: Titanium.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    success : function(event) {

     var galleryImage = event.media;
     Ti.API.info('gallery  ==' + galleryImage);

     var blobStream = Ti.Stream.createStream({ source: galleryImage, mode: Ti.Stream.MODE_READ });
     var newBuffer = Ti.createBuffer({ length: galleryImage.length });
     
     var bytes = blobStream.read(newBuffer);
     
     

     var height = galleryImage.height;
     var width = galleryImage.width;
     var pos = (height - width) / 4;
     var dict = {
      x : 0,
      y : 50,
      width : '35%',
      height :'35%'
     };

Comment: var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView({
      image : newImageBlob,
      height : 'auto',
      width : 'auto'
     });

     $.container.add(imageView);

    },
    cancel : function() {

    },
    savedToPhotoGallery : true,
    allowEditing:true,
    mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
    showControls:true

Comment: I've added your code to the first post. You didn't mention custom user cropping in the question and you have another question about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968170/is-their-any-module-which-allow-the-user-can-able-to-crop-the-image-dynamically where you can find a module that does so

Comment: See example 2 in my answer. It corrects your code and adds cropping to a fixed image size