# Is there any module which allows cropping an image dynamically in Appcelerator for iOS platform?

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I am developing an ios mobile app.In that my requirement is user should able to allow  crop the photo gallery images dynamically.is their any free module or any alternate code  to achieve my requirement

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://gitt.io to search for modules. You'll find:

https://github.com/caspahouzer/TiCropImageEditor
(forked from https://github.com/EtnaTraining/TiCropImageEditor with 64bit and some other patches)

The modules implement [PEPhotoCropEditor](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor)

Comment: Thanks  a lot for giving response and also solution for my requirement

Comment: no problem; there is an example folder in the github repo if you need some help. If there are problems use the issue section on github

Comment: yep. I like my module too ;)

Answer (score 0):

Also check https://gist.github.com/FokkeZB/5501222 and https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.imagefactory

Related to the topic but maybe not suited for your case is https://github.com/jwagner/smartcrop-cli, which I use myself (but in another context)